# How much pressure do boost and jettison fuel pumps produce?

Tags: fuel, boeing-777, fuel-systems, boeing-767

What is the pressure output of a (boost) fuel pump on a Boeing 767 and/or 777, compared to a heavy-duty jettison fuel pump.

Answer (score 2):

I looked up a cannister boost pump and jettison fuel pump on the [Eaton](https://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Aerospace/Fuel/PCT_247872#tabs-2) website and found a cannister boost pump for the 747 that puts out 28,000 Pounds Per Hour, and a jettison pump also for the 747 that puts out 40,000 PPH.  Safe to say jettison pumps generally have a higher output than engine boost pumps, for obvious reasons.

Comment: This answers volume; the question asked about pressure. Although I'd agree that especially for a jettison pump, PPH matters more than PSI.

Comment: @RalphJ depending on the type of pump PSI doesnt matter, if the pump is positive displacement (which the unit of PPH seems to imply) the pressure is a result of the system around the pump not the pump itself